# Integer value, if not type cast to double in a math operation gives baffling results

Tags: visual-c++

I am running a small MFC project on VS 2015 - x64. Just checking the result of a float operation.

```
float fScale = 0.0199999996;
float fOffset = 0;
    
double doubleX2 = fOffset + 1 * fScale;
```

Only the `fOffset` is changed in a 'for()' loop, from 0 to 3000000. The fScale remains the same always.

results:

```
fOffset            doubleX2
0.000000                0.020000
63.000000              63.020000
64.000000              64.019997
127.000000            127.019997
128.000000            128.020004
255.000000            255.020004
256.000000            256.019989
511.000000            511.019989
512.000000            512.020020
8191.000000          8191.020020
8192.000000          8192.019531
65535.000000        65535.019531
65536.000000        65536.023438
131071.000000      131071.023438
131072.000000      131072.015625
262143.000000      262143.015625
262144.000000      262144.031250
524287.000000      524287.031250
524288.000000      524288.000000
1999999.000000    1999999.000000
2999999.000000    2999999.000000
```

I have no idea why the decimal part varies and becomes zero eventually.
I was expecting the decimal part to be 0.0199999996 always.
But If I type cast the integer '1' with double type, the decimal part is always '.020000'.

Comment: As written, the expression is computed in `float`, and then converted to `double` at the end, on assignment. If you change `1` to `1.0`, then the whole expression is computed in `double`, and you have a less pronounced loss of precision. `float` is accurate to ~7 decimal digits, `double` to ~15.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There Float is an high value Data Structure in C++, it can store values from Around - 3x10^38 to +3x10^38 . Double is another Extremely high value Data Structure which stores around -1x10^308 to +1x10^308. Whereas Int is small When Compared to these Structures.

-> Float has an Decimal Precision about 6 Digits, where as Double Has an Decimal Precision of 15 Digits.

->Suppose If You Convert 900.0000000f to Double The Value Stored in the Double Will Just Be the 900.

-> Computer Uses Binary to Convert Float to Decimal, First it Converts Float to Binary , So Converting High Precision Numbers to Binary Will pop out slight Errors in Precision.
So You may not Always Get the Assumed Value.
In the header file  There's an Manipulator Called std::setprecision(precision)
You can Use That to Control the Precision of the Number.

-> This can be Ignored if the Calculation is small number or any other unimportant number.
Still If You think You need the Precision You Need to Do Error Analysis.

This Link has Some Good Explanation
https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/propagation/